# Firebase error no debug.keystore in .android folder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-keystore

I tried to connect Firebase to my android app but the error says

> Firebase: Could not find keystore in file ({0}) specified for debug
>   build type. {2}

I see that there is no debug.keystore in my .android folder.

Comment: Have you tried to do **Build - Rebuild Project** from the Android Studio? That will generate the debug keystore automatically

Comment: Yes I did. But it didn't help :/

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue, for fixing it, I've done the following step

1. Go to [your google firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/) account
2. Click on Project Settings
3. Download the google-services.json file and save it in {your-project}/app/google-services.json
4. The rebuild your project and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Open your project structure **File -> Project structure**

Than goto **Signing**, if you use default key clear all fill like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldm89.png), or select **debug** and set up correct path to your keystore file (fill **Store File**). In Linux, by default, it is ~/.android/debug.keystore.

Also, goto **Build Types**, and select **debug** and you see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yp7q.png), if you cleaned fills in previouse step your **Signing Config** must be **empty**, else select **debug**

Hope it's help you.

Comment: This is about firebase, not Key Signing