# Failed to connect with Firebase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to connect my Android APP with Firebase, these are something I've already tried and checked.

A. Connected from Firebase console and doing the SDK set up.

1.The Package name, SHA1 in Firebase console are correct.

2.Latest version of google-services.json file and placed it in app.

3.The package names in google-services.json are correct.

4.The dependency in the app level gradle with plugin

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

5.The dependency in project level 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

6.Latest version of Google Play Services and Google Repository in SDK Manager.

7.Uninstall the APP and run again.

The problem occurred at the forth step, checking the connection with a continuous progress bar but unable to connect.

B. Connect from Android studio assistant

The dialog showed "This app is already connected to a project "SampleProject".Click "Sync" to update the configuration information."

After Sync, the Event Log showed

Firebase: Couldnt find keystore in file ({0}) specified for release build type. {2}

Firebase: Firebase project created and connected locally to module: app.

I'm not sure whether the problem occurred here or not, is there any other options to resolve this problem? Many Thanks!

**update**

After struggling on this problem for one day, the problem doesn't solved, but I used a tricky way to avoid the problem. Connected my APP with Fabric crashlytics rather than connect with Firebase directly, then connect Firebase with Fabric. The process would be APP->Fabric->Firebase. May the alternative way help someone facing similar problem.

Comment: Please add the content of your both build.gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

A possible problem may be with

> 5.The dependency in project level classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

Try using  `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Something else that you can try is changing

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'`

Also, check to make sure that

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

is at the bottom of your app level build.gradle file.

Another problem may be that your google-services.json file is in the wrong location. Make sure that in Android Studio, it looks like this for you:

[image]

Hopefully, this should fix your problems. If it doesn't please post a screenshot of the place where you think it is not working.

Comment: Thank you for response, I placed it at the correct position and change the google service version, but the problem doesn't be fixed. This is where I doubt the problem occurred. https://ppt.cc/fqwESx

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143051/firebase-error-no-debug-keystore-in-android-folder  but it doesn't help either.

Comment: Usually when I connect an app to Firebase I don't use the SHA. Just try it without it and see if that works. Otherwise the only thing that I can think of is maybe that you accidentally renamed "google-services.json". I did this once and I got the same problem. Also make sure that you see it underneath Project, not Android.  You may also want to follow Firebase's documentation in the link below to make sure that you have done it properly. Here is the link:   https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are having? Is there an error message popping up when you run the app, or is it just that the app is not able to connect with Firebase? **I have made some changes to my answer above**. Try changing the firebase core from 16.0.4 to 16.0.3

Comment: Unfortunately I tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work, I found another way to avoid the problem, just connect with Fabric then transfer the data to Firebase so that I don't need to build the connection with Firebase. Even so I truly appreciate all your help on this matter.

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you for the upvote. I am happy that you found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Latest version of google-services.json file and placed it in app. ???
```

after you downloaded it from the fire-base project settings and after you added it to your project. Did you made rebuild project from the android studio build menu or not ?

Comment: Indeed I forgot to rebuild it... but after I rebuild, the problem doesn't solved...